# In a ggplot2 plot, changing legend name results in showing names twice

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics, tukey

I'm trying to plot interactions plot with Tukey confidence intervals. Plot the difference in length depending on dose and supp. These things already work in the example I show at the bottom of the question.

I would like to show different linetypes, different shapes and different colours but only to differentiate 2 options supp(OJ or VC). OJ dotted line, blue, with mean as a circle, VC normal line, red, with mean as a square.

My two problems are:

1. if I set shapes and colors, then when changing legend name (scale_colour_discrete(name = "SUPPrename")) I end up getting two different legends.
2. I could add different shapes as mean, and different line colours, but couldn't change linetype too.

[image]

```
library("ggpubr")
require("dplyr")
data("ToothGrowth")

# Ahora  tukey con anova two ways 
# Store the data in the variable df
df <- ToothGrowth

# Show a random sample
set.seed(1234)
dplyr::sample_n(df, 10)

# Convert dose as a factor and recode the levels        # as "D0.5", "D1", "D2"
df$dose <- factor(df$dose,
                  levels = c(0.5, 1, 2),
                  labels = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"))




# MF anova      # Two-way ANOVA with interaction effect     # These two calls are equivalent
#res.aov3 <- aov(len ~ supp * dose, data = df)
res.aov3 <- aov(len ~ supp + dose + supp:dose, data = df)
summary(res.aov3)

# Use TukeyHSD
tukeyHSD <- TukeyHSD(res.aov3, which = "dose")
plot(tukeyHSD)

# Allans response 
tukeyCI <- (tukeyHSD$dose[1, 1] - tukeyHSD$dose[1, 2]) / 2


print("Example of an error that happens when I set different point shapes and change the leyends name.")
ggplot(df, aes(x = dose, y = len, color = supp, group = supp)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, fun.ymin = function(x) mean(x) - tukeyCI, fun.ymax = function(x) mean(x) + tukeyCI, geom = "errorbar", size = 1, color = 'gray50', width = 0.25) +
               scale_shape_manual(values = 21:26) + 
               stat_summary(fun.y = function(x) mean(x), geom = "line", aes(group = supp)) +
               stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 3, aes(shape = supp), col = "black", fill = 'white') + 
               theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
               theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black")) +
               scale_colour_discrete(name = "NewName ERROR")
```

- version R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
- packageVersion("ggplot2") ‘3.1.0’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your legends merged you have to use the same name for both `legends` which IMHO is best done via `labs`. Not sure what's the issue with the linetype but you add it to the `stat_summary` adding the lines and of course in that case set the name for the `linetype` legend too.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = dose, y = len, color = supp, group = supp)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, fun.ymin = function(x) mean(x) - tukeyCI, fun.ymax = function(x) mean(x) + tukeyCI, geom = "errorbar", size = 1, color = 'gray50', width = 0.25) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 21:26) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = function(x) mean(x), geom = "line", aes(group = supp, linetype = supp)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 3, aes(shape = supp), col = "black", fill = 'white') + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black")) +
  labs(color = "NewName ERROR", shape = "NewName ERROR", linetype = "NewName ERROR")
```

[image]